# MigLayout - I have two scrollpanes, I want the edge between them to be draggable. How would I do this?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I have two JScrollPanes, right next to each other. I want to be able to resize their width by cannibalizing the neighbour by dragging the edge between them either left or right.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Use [JSplitPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html).

Comment: Maybe add a third plane in between as the dragable?